# How to reuse postgres database connection client across multiple AWS Lambda invocations?

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda, layer, pg

I have a lambda which connects to postgres database using '[pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg)' package. Every time i create a new database connection, execute the query and close the connection. Lambda can invoke multiple times. How can i use the DB connection across all lambda executions so that no need to create a new connection every time.

Comment: Why we need to reuse connection?

Comment: _Don't close_ the connection…?! It can remain open and will be reused if the same Lambda instance happens to get reused.

Comment: not closing the connection might cause the database resource errors, when the traffic is considerable. right? You might be able to reuse the client as long as it is in the lambda_handler() method

Comment: @Ananth When the traffic is considerable, then the overhead of closing and reopening connections will make the situation _even worse_. If you're worried about "considerable traffic", use an RDS Proxy which will pool and share connections to reduce the impact on the actual database.

Answer (score 2):

You can reuse the client itself by generating it in the function handler's constructor, so it stays as long as the lambda function is warm, but gets recreated on cold starts. As for the connection itself, if you close it, it's closed.

Comment: How about using pg-pool   https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-pool